# Tracking down a SIGSEGV…

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, clang

So I've got this weird **SIGSEGV** happening at very few (less than 1%) of my users…

From the stack trace it looks like an over-release

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x00007fff9a3f916f objc_release + 31
1   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x00007fff9a3f7ac4 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 475
2   CoreFoundation                       0x00007fff9cc5c102 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 49
3   Foundation                           0x00007fff96992cb6 -[NSAutoreleasePool drain] + 152
4   AppKit                               0x00007fff9138409b -[NSApplication run] + 892
5   AppKit                               0x00007fff91306520 NSApplicationMain + 1175
6   RailModeller Pro                     0x000000010b60578b main (main.m:30)
7   libdyld.dylib                        0x00007fff9a36b5ad start + 0
```

..but no matter what I try,

- even with the very same data,
- following the exact same steps as the users,
- same OS/patch level,
- using Address Sanitizer (Xcode 7.3),
- using Zombies instrument,
- using Guard Malloc

all appears to be fine.

The function crashing is a pretty common one in the app and I'd be drowning in bug reports (both from the automated bug reporting system as well as users getting in touch) if this were a more common issue.

However, to these (<1%) users the app appears effectively unusable.

***Any*** hints on how to track down this issue much appreciated!

Comment: I would start by running "analyze" and then manually checking all `__bridge` casts. If you can't reproduce an issue (being that memory issue or any other kind of issue), finding it is always difficult.

Comment: ..none of them (`__bridge`) in my code & I'm using the static analyzer on a regular basis (& fixing the issues..)

Comment: If you cannot reproduce it and the stack trace is not illuminating, there's no easy way to solve the issue. It's quite possible that the cause is a buffer overflow or underflow write somewhere, and often this sort of problem does not cause the violation at the time of the write, but rather at some point later where the data that was damaged needs to be used. Every experienced developer has felt your pain at one time or another.

Comment: The crash seems to be related to `NSAutoreleasePool`. Make sure to use the `@autoreleasepool {}` syntax rather than `[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]` and `drain`

Comment: Could be different scheduling (a race condition) due to different hardware (CPU cores, etc.) or whatever else is running. Also, check the binary images listed in the crash report for anything that's neither Apple's nor yours. If your users are willing and the problem is very reproducible for them, you could have them run with `NSZombieEnabled=YES`. If nothing else, that should give you the class of object that's over-released. I don't know if `MallocStackLoggingNoCompact=1` will help produce a better crash report, but it might. (It would help if you were directly debugging.)

Comment: @KenThomases Good point - it's 100% reproducible for these very few so `NSZombieEnabled` is definitely worth a try - cheers!

Comment: @Jay hey were you able to figure this issue? I am facing similar crash which not able to reproduce locally.